# OAuth2: Force HWIOAuthBundle install with Symfony 6.3

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I would like to use HWIOAuthBundle to Symfony 6.3

Officially from the composer perspective, HWIOAuthBundle is compatible with Symfony v5.4.28.

- "hwi/oauth-bundle 1.4.5 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4|^5.1 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.49, v5.1.0, ..., v5.4.28] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.3.*)."

But in the documentation it was tested and validated for Symfony 6.3 and php 8.3 : https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/commit/48f3d487e9bc77cea8dc162cc27e9c546d1ef26f

How to force the install of the Bundle with SF6.3.*?

- I also tried with "knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle" (Succeeded to login with Google OAuth, but not succeeded to use it together with JWT and Passport...), from the 6.3 version I saw that we now use "Access Token Authenticator" and other options...

After 3 days of research and tests, I'm confused about the current best practice to implement the OAuth2 for google, with Symfony 6.3.*, and integrate it with the Symfony JWT Authentication.

Can you please help me with

- a way to force the install of HWIOAuthBundle.
- or a link or at least an Idea of the best practices/Bundles to: 1) login with Google OAuth2, 2) use it with JWT with the last version of Symfony. Anything will help me.

Thx in advance!
Thierry

Comment: I remember going through this sort of thing years ago.  Not the composer stuff but trying to integrate these "highly engineered" auth bundles.  I finally said to heck with it and just looked at the oauth2 protocol, made a few http requests and viola I had authentication.  Very little code actually needed.  I won't say it is best practice by any means but at the very least you will learn quite a bit.

Comment: I see you also posted on the Symfony Discussion board.  That is good. Maybe you will get different advice. Though complaining about unsupported third party bundles is always a risk.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are encountering that is because the most recent "released" version of HWI is v 1.4.5 from 2021. The commit you have is to the development branch, which is part of the current work for the not yet released version 2 which is still in Beta.

At your own risk you can choose to install the beta version or the dev-master branch -- again, both are *NOT* released code yet using
`composer require  hwi/oauth-bundle:^dev-master`